# how to run parallel tasks in ansible with when: inventory_host="ip" ? its running sequential

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

inventory file :

[hosts-DR]

host1

host2

host3

host4

---

- host: hosts-DR

  roles:

  -role: stop-Servers

stop-servers role files are  like below.

```
serverstop.yml
main.yml
```

main.yml content

main.yml :

- include:serverstop.yml

serverstop.yml content

- name: execute a task on all servers parallel

  shell: command1
- name: execute a task only on host1

  shell: command 2 for only host1

  when: inventory_hostname== host1
- name: execute a task only on host2

  shell: command 3 for only host2

  when: inventory_hostname== host2
- name: execute a task only on host3

  shell: command 4 for only host3

  when: inventory_hostname== host3
- name: execute a task only on host4

  shell: command 5 for only host4

  when: inventory_hostname== host4

first task is running parallel on all hosts , remaining tasks are running sequential . I need to trigger them parallel . I used async and poll 0 , but I need to run host 1 and host2  tasks at a time and based on result need to run host 3 and host4 parallel.
unable to capture async_status as well . can anyone help please ? strategy: free is not allowed with my python installation version . Please help

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow! please format your question properly (wrap the code sections with " ``` " ) also make sure to read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (if you've not already)

Answer (score 1):

Forget the async stuff, and use `or` in your `when` clause.  You seem to be using different commands for different clients.  The commands should be put into the inventory, but they can be done with `set_fact`:

```
  - name: Set command for host1
    set_fact:
      command: ls -1 /
    when: inventory_hostname == 'host1'

  - name: Set command for host2
    set_fact:
      command: ls -l /
    when: inventory_hostname == 'host2'

  - name: Show variables
    debug:
      var: command

  - name: Run commands
    shell: "{{ command }}"
    when:  inventory_hostname == 'host1' or inventory_hostname == 'host2'
    register: result

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      var: result
    when:  inventory_hostname == 'host1' or inventory_hostname == 'host2'
```

Then do the same with host3 and host4 commands.

---

### EDIT

I'd like to point out that your playbook is not portable to another inventory, and that's a Bad Thing.  So, let's change your inventory to something like this:

```
[independent]
host1 command="ls -1 /"
host2 command="ls -l /"

[dependent]
host3 command="who am i"
host4 command="whoami"
```

Now, we can avoid setting those commands in the playbook, and run on groups instead of hosts:

```
  - name: Run commands on independent hosts
    shell: "{{ command }}"
    when:  inventory_hostname in groups['independent']
    register: result

  - name: Show results
    debug:
      var: result
    when:  inventory_hostname in groups['independent']
```

To get the `result` value, look to `hostvars`: `hostvars['host1'].result`.  I do not know how you are relating the result from one host to decide what to do on another.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution building up on Jack's: put you commands in a dict which keys are `inventory_hostname` and play the ones defined.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  
  vars:
    phase1_custom_commands:
      host1: command for host1
      host2: command for host2
      host4: command for host4

  tasks:
    - name: Play phase 1 custom commands for defined hosts
      command: "{{ phase1_custom_commands[inventory_hostname] }}"
      when: phase1_custom_commands[inventory_hostname] is defined
```